# caching different versions of page based on querystring params?

Tags: caching, query-string, typo3

I have a page that displays different content based on a parameter in the querystring.  At the moment I have caching disabled on the page.  Is there a way to make Typo3 cache a version for each different URL accessing the page (or each combination of querystring params)?

Comment: What kind of links they are ? are you creating them in your extension, or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you do not use the API:
http://typo3.org/documentation/article/the-mysteries-of-chash-1

Always create your link with `typolink`.

Since 6.x you can configure some required parameters in the install tool.